# Print positive numbers with plus sign

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am calculating the difference between years and a reference year. I'd like to use the result as the x-values in a plot. But how can I print a + sign with the positive numbers (-2, -1, 0, +1, +2)?

```
dat <- data.frame(year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004), ref = rep(2002)) 
dat$diff <- dat$year - dat$ref

ggplot(dat, aes(x = diff))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004), ref = rep(2002)) 
dat$diff <- dat$year - dat$ref
ggplot(dat, aes(x = diff)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) sprintf("%+d", x))
```

Comment: this is perfect, just one minor detail: is it possible to only print the + for positive numbers but not for 0?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with `sprintf` (check `?sprintf`), however `scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) ifelse(x>0, paste0("+", x), x))` should work.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be accomplished with the obscure `symnum` function and the trusty `paste0`. Here, 0 does not get a "+" prepended to it.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = diff)) + 
   scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(symnum(x, c(-Inf, 0, Inf), c("", "+")), x))
```